# Am I misapplying coefficient of variation?

Tags: statistical-significance, mean, standard-deviation, coefficient-of-variation

I'm working with proteomics data in python, and I want to implement an abundance cutoff as described by K. Podwojski, et al (short section attached below). My goal is to quantify the difference in abundance of each phosphopeptide between control and experimental group, then filter out the ones that may not have been biologically relevant differences. We could simply use average log fold change, but my mentor thinks CV would be a better way to compare.

Unfortunately, it's been a few years since I took statistics, and I'm confused about which columns to use for the coefficient of variation. Since I have three groups - a control (WT) and two experimental groups, I had to consider if I should include the control or not. I'm comfortable with the rest of the procedure.

My mentor suggested to calculate the CV using experimental groups only, so I would be calculating the mean and SD for columns O, P, Q, and R or for columns S, T, U, and V. If this is right, I don't understand how I can use CV to compare the differences in abundance, since it has nothing to do with the controls.

It seems like including the control would allow for that comparison. However, for proteins that increased, that would decrease the mean; for proteins that decreased, that would increase the mean. SD would go up in either case. Then the CV would be high for proteins that decrease and low for proteins that increase, which is not my intention.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Surely I'm misunderstanding something (or a whole lot). Thanks in advance!

---

I've attached an example of my data and the section from Podwojski for reference.

[image: My data]

[image: CV formula]